# Go, pgx: SELECT query returns only one row

Tags: postgresql, go, pgx

Golang, pgx:
I am trying to get all rows from t_example (currently 20 items), however for some reason only one returns (the first one). I tried to debug and rows.Next() returns false after the first iteration.
Could you please help me with advice?

I'm a newbie, but I've tried to find similar cases here in advance :)

My code:

```
func (ts *exampleStorage) GetAll() *[]Example {
q := `SELECT id, name FROM t_example`

rows := ts.client.Query(context.Background(), q)

example := make([]Example, 0)

for rows.Next() {
    var ex Example
    rows.Scan(&ex.Id, &ex.Name)
    example = append(example, ex)
}

return &example
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't check for errors :

- `row.Scan(&ex.Id, &ex.Name)` could return an error (and, in `pgx` implementation, this error is fatal for the `rows` iteration) :

```golang
    err := rows.Scan(&ex.Id, &ex.Name)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("*** rows.Scan error: %s", err)
        return nil, err
    }
```

- there is a gotcha with `sql.Rows / pgx.Rows` error checking : you should check if an error occurred *after* exiting the `for rows.Next() {` loop :

```golang
for rows.Next() {
    ...
}
// check rows.Err() after the last rows.Next() :
if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
    // on top of errors triggered by bad conditions on the 'rows.Scan()' call,
    // there could also be some bad things like a truncated response because
    // of some network error, etc ...
    fmt.Printf("*** iteration error: %s", err)
    return nil, err
}

return example, nil
```

---

*a side note* : in the vast majority of cases you don't want to return a pointer to a slice (e.g: `*[]Example`) but a slice (e.g: `[]Example`)

Comment: LeGEC, thanks a lot I could find the error.

Comment: About a side note - thank you for the advice! Could you please share some references?

Comment: https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro , https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/7